# Understanding the BAML MOVE index

Tags: options, implied-volatility, bond-yields, vix, bond-futures

Hello quant community.

I am looking for more information about a very interesting index: BAML-ICE MOVE index. There is very little literature online that details how the index levels are calculated beyond. This is surprising given the wealth of information available about the SPX volatility tracker VIX.

One piece is RateLabs' *'The MOVE Index'*.

Does anyone have any idea about how the index values are calculated?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: My understanding of MOVE is that it is the equivalent of VIX, but on US Treasuries. So it is a measure of the implied vol of Treasury options, essentially.

Comment: Thanks Jan - VIX is calculated in a very well documented and specific way https://cdn.cboe.com/resources/indices/documents/vvix-termstructure.pdf
Hoping to find something like this

Comment: Hmm, not sure where to find it, since it's BAML proprietary index, unlikely they'd share the exact methodology, as others could then exactly replicate it and the uniqueness of the BAML MOVE would then disappear. But if you manage to find the exact formula, please post it here in the comments, as I am sure many quants would be interested in this (including myself).

Comment: DES page on BBG has some details but probably not to the extent you're looking for..?

Comment: Would you be able to please link the page you're referring to? Can't find it myself...